# VoiceOver announces dimmed instead of disabled for buttons

Tags: ios, mobile, ios8, accessibility, voiceover

iOS 8.x VoiceOver announces dimmed instead of disabled for buttons that have been disabled. Is there a way to programmatically get VoiceOver to say "disabled" instead of "dimmed"?

Comment: Is that what the system does for other apps as well? Does it say dimmed in Apple's own apps?

Comment: Yes, this is a feature that Apple uses for disable buttons. I just don't think it accurate. I am going to follow ChrisCM advice and leave it as it is.

Answer (score 12):

There are ways to do what you want, but you absolutely should not use them.  The announcement "Dimmed" occurs, when the `User Interaction Enabled` trait is set to `NO`.  This is the way VoiceOver users are use to on screen, focusable, but disabled elements being announced.  Forcing your app to behave in another manner is poor accessibility (See WCAG 2.0 Guideline 3.2.3).

Something you can do, if you want it to be truly disabled, is set `isAccessibilityElement` to `NO`.  Then it won't even be in the VoiceOver focus loop.  Then just set it to `YES`, when you want to enable it.  But, if you want to leave it within the focus loop, "Dimmed" is the appropriate announcement for a temporarily disabled UI element.

My vote would be for the first solution, as modifying the `isAccessibilityElement` dynamically is a form of dynamic content, and may need additional considerations to maintain proper accessibility (See WCAG 2.0 Guideline 3.2.1 and 3.2.2).  Unless there are a lot of such buttons, and flicking through them is tedious, in which case implementing the dynamic element considerations is worth it to maintain good VoiceOver usability.

Comment: Thanks, I was concerned with WCAG 2.0 Guideline 4.1.2. I would prefer it to say 'disabled' since that is its correct state but I will leave like it is. Doing isAccessibilityElement=NO is not a choice I would prefer since the VoiceOver user would not know that it is but a visual user would.

Comment: What about the `NotEnabled` trait?

Comment: The "UIAccessibilityTraitNotEnabled" is the same thing as "User Interaction Enabled".  One is from the point of view of the StoryBoard, one is the variable name for the UIAccessibilityTraits type.  But they refer to the same thing.  For some reason the StoryBoard references it as a positive, and the bitmask constant as a negative.  It's confusing, but they are actually the same value.