# Talkback announces "dimmed" instead of "disabled" for buttons and checkboxes

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Similar to this iOS-question ( [VoiceOver announces dimmed instead of disabled for buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283878/voiceover-announces-dimmed-instead-of-disabled-for-buttons) ) I have the same problem, but for Android devices with Talkback.

Why is Talkback announcing some elements like buttons or checkboxes as "dimmed" instead of "disabled"?

Should I somehow change this, or leave it as Talkback reads it? If I should change it to "disabled / dimmed" so that it's consistent over the whole app, how?

---

[EDIT]:

Example:

[image: dimmed checkbox]

It seems that not only buttons use "dimmed", but check / tick boxes as well.

Also only the english language seems to use "dimmed", in german it's still read as "deaktiviert" (disabled).

Comment: The question is now about checkboxes as well, not only buttons anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change it. TalkBack is responding to properties in ways that users would be accustomed to. Sometimes the default behavior is the most accessible because it is expected, even when it isn't quite ideal.

If you would like an answer to the "why" I would need more information on the particular examples that your talking about. Are there apps that exhibit this behavior? TalkBack updated not too long ago, but I generally hear the "disabled" announcement over the "dimmed" announcement from TalkBack from the "obvious" times that such an announcement would apply. I certainly wouldn't expect there to be a general distinction between the two.

Also, I'm looking through the current version of TalkBack (again TalkBack has been updated recently, so the open source version may not be up to date and available) and can't find the localized string "dimmed" anywhere. There are references to "screen dimmed" but this is certainly different from what you're talking about. Which suggests to me that the "dimmed" announcement is coming from changes in the code that I would recommend be UNDONE, so as to allow the "disabled" announcement that TalkBack users would be accustomed to. This sounds to me like something someone coming from an iOS background wanted to duplicate. The behavior in iOS is to announce disabled things as "dimmed". Duplicating this on Android would absolutely be innapropriate. Let TalkBack do its thing!

Providing code examples would be helpful for me to be more sure about all of these things, your question is quite ambiguous.  What types of controls? A Button for example may behave different from a Tab in a TabWidget, and this may be intentional. The way your question is worded, any more specific answers than I have given would be speculative.

EDIT:

The different parts of this announcement:

Every Sunday (0): The text of the control

Tick Box: The calculated role of the control. In stock Android this will announce as "CheckBox" (I'm testing on 7.0, with the current GitHub TalkBack). Samsung would be best off to leave this as "Check Box" from stock Android OS, I don't know why they felt the need to change "Check Box" to "Tick Box" just to be different. Doing things just to be different is annoying, there is no objective difference between "Check Box" and "Tick Box" (licensing???).

Not Selected: The current calculated state of the control. In Stock Android this would read out as "Not Checked". Unless the app is overriding this, Samsung would seem to be mucking with this as well. They should stop doing so, but again, out of your control and best left alone. Samsung users will be used to this. Though ultimately I find "Not Selected" to be a little ambiguous in terms of a CheckBox control. "Not Ticked" I think would be better.

Dimmed: Again, another thing that, unless your code is overriding (which I don't think it can in this case for this bit of calculated state). This is the calculated enable/disabled state of the control. In stock Android this would read out as "disabled". Again, leave this alone. Samsung would ALSO be best to leave this alone.

It would definitely appear that Samsung is doing strange things to the Accessibility read outs of calculated components. I'm not sure what version of Android this Samsung flavor is built off of, but I don't believe those read outs have changed. I know CheckBox and Disabled have been the same since 4.2 - 7.0 (probably Android O as well.). These minor changes fracture the Android Accessibility Ecosystem. For these particular elements, Samsung would definitely be best off just to leave them alone. HOWEVER, given that Samsung has made these changes, you are best off NOT fixing this fragmentation. Let Samsung users and Nexus users and Motorola users experience things in the way they are used to and get accustomed to their devices. Allow default behaviors unless overriding them is absolutely necessary. Hearing "disabled" when your expecting "dimmed" is confusing, not to mention a maintenance nightmare should Samsung decide NOT to override this any more or vice versa. When the OS is "calculating" state and doing so reasonably... let it happen!

Comment: My assumption was too that it's better to not change it at all. I did not find any Google-app that shows this behaviour, but only our own app does it. I've checked our string ressources / project, but the word "dimmed" is nowhere used, so it comes from Android itself. The device is a Samsung Galaxy A5, Samsung seems to change accessibility quite a bit, maybe it's a Samsung-problem?

Comment: May I ask as well to which open source Talkback you are referring? I only did find the "eyes-free" project source here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/eyes-free/source ... but this Talkback seems to be rather old (version 3.5.1)? The Talkback on the phones seem to be 5.0.3 and 5.2.1. Or did you check the Android source code for Talkback itself?

Comment: GitHub open source project. https://github.com/google/talkback. Samsung may definitely be going thing in their OS impelmentation. My recommendation would still be to leave it alone. Same reasoning.

Comment: The GitHub Talkback seems to be not the newest version, but I will look into it. Thanks for the link and the explanation, this helps me to understand the reasoning behind the "why is it dimmed".

Comment: They'll push the "newest" version eventually. It will never by truly in sync, but it's as close as you can get without actually having access to Google's private TalkBack fork.